# How does numpy's indexing work in this scenario

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

How does plot numpy's logical indexing get the datapoints from the "data" variable in the code snippet below? I understand that the first parameter is the x co-ordinate and the second parameter is the y co-ordinate. I am unsure of how it maps to the datapoints from the variable.

```
data = vstack((rand(150,2) + array([.5,.5]),rand(150,2)))
# assign each sample to a cluster
idx,_ = vq(data,centroids)

# some plotting using numpy's logical indexing
plot(data[idx==0,0],data[idx==0,1],'ob',
             data[idx==1,0],data[idx==1,1],'or')
plot(centroids[:,0],centroids[:,1],'sg',markersize=8)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all in the shapes:

```
In [89]: data.shape
Out[89]: (300, 2)    # data has 300 rows and 2 columns
In [93]: idx.shape
Out[93]: (300,)      # idx is a 1D-array with 300 elements
```

`idx == 0` is a boolean array with the same shape as `idx`. It is `True` wherever an element in `idx` equals `0`:

```
In [97]: (idx==0).shape
Out[97]: (300,)
```

When you index `data` with `idx==0`, you get all rows of `data` where `idx==0` is True:

```
In [98]: data[idx==0].shape
Out[98]: (178, 2)
```

When you index using a tuple, `data[idx==0, 0]`, the first axis of `data` is indexed with the boolean array `idx==0`, and the second axis of `data` is indexed with `0`:

```
In [99]: data[idx==0, 0].shape
Out[99]: (178,)
```

The first axis of `data` correspond to rows, the second axis corresponds to columns. So you get just the first column of `data[idx==0]`. Since the first column of `data` are `x`-values, this gives you those `x`-values in `data` where `idx==0`.